# The current path didn’t match any of these. Django Project/ Learning_Log

Tags: python, django, http-status-code-404

I am studying working with Django from a book Python Crash Course by Eric Matthes.
I follow all recommendations and write code one-to-one like in a book, but i have encountered such a problem. I cant go to detailed topic page from a topics link, but manually i can.

> Using the URLconf defined in learning_log.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:
> admin/
> users/
> [name='index']
> topics/ [name='topics']
> topics/<int:topic_id>/ [name='topic']
> new_topic/ [name='new_topic']
> new_entry/<int:topic_id>/ [name='new_entry']
> edit_entry/<int:entry_id>/ [name='edit_entry']
> The current path, topics/% url 'learning_logs:topic' topic.id %, didn’t match any of these.

So, my code is presented below. I really don't understand what i do wrong.

My url patterns:

```
from django.urls import path, re_path
from . import views
app_name = 'learning_logs'
urlpatterns = [
    # Home page
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    # Page with the list of all topics
    path('topics/', views.topics, name='topics'),
    # Page with detailed topic information
    path('topics/<int:topic_id>/', views.topic, name='topic'),
]
```

topics templates

```
{% extends "learning_logs\base.html" %}

{% block content %}

  <p> Topics</p>

  {% if topics %}
    <ul>
      {% for topic in topics %}
      <li>
        <a href="% url 'learning_logs:topic' topic.id %">{{ topic }}</a>
      </li>
      {% endfor %}
    </ul>
    {% else %}
      <p>No topics have been added yet.</p>
    {% endif %}
    <a href="{% url 'learning_logs:new_topic' %}">Add a new topic:</a>

{% endblock content %}
```

topic templates

```
{% extends "learning_logs/base.html" %}

{% block content %}

  <p> Topic: {{ topic }}</p>

  <p> Entries:</p>

  <p>
    <a href="{% url 'learning_logs:new_entry' topic.id %}">Add new entry</a>
  </p>

  <ul>
  {% for entry in entries %}
    <li>
      <p>{{ entry.date_added|date:'M d, Y H:i' }}</p>
      <p>{{ entry.text|linebreaks }}</p>
      <p>
        <a href="{% url 'learning_logs:edit_entry' entry.id %}">Edit entry</a>
      </p>
    </li>
  {% empty %}
    <li>No entries have been added yet.</li>
  {% endfor %}
  </ul>

{% endblock content %}
```

and views

```
def index(request):
    # Home page
    return render(request, 'learning_logs/index.html')

def topics(request):
    # Shows all topic
    topics = Topic.objects.order_by('date_added')
    context = {'topics': topics}
    return render(request, 'learning_logs/topics.html', context)

def topic(request, topic_id):
    topic = Topic.objects.get(id=topic_id)
    entries = topic.entry_set.order_by('-date_added')
    context = {'topic': topic, 'entries': entries}
    return render(request, 'learning_logs/topic.html', context)
```

Please can someone explain me what i should do to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

The braces are missing around the URL generating code, so the browser uses the template code as a relative URL segment (`topics/` + `% url 'learning_logs:topic' topic.id %`).

```
<a href="{% url 'learning_logs:topic' topic.id %}">{{ topic }}</a>
```

Comment: Ohh... Thanks a lot! Next time i ll be more attentive!